# Получить значения переменных из файла php посредством ajax

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать следующее:

Есть файл php где объявлены некоторые переменные, значения которых берутся из БД

```
$x = 12345;
$y = 23;
```

Нужно в JS посредством ajax получить значения этих переменных, подскажите как это реализовать без использования библиотек.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот почитайте:

[AJAX запрос без использования JS фреймворков](http://www.xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/ajax/ajax-request.html)